# Insert statement not returning record id (@rid)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, orientdb, graph-databases

OK, so I'm running a simple SQL `INSERT` on OrientDB, using Ruby and [OrientDb4r](https://github.com/veny/orientdb4r)

However, whenever I try to get the `@rid` of the just-inserted record, I'm getting back the full record.

```
$client.command "INSERT INTO #{ MY_CLASS }(#{ MY_FIELDS }) VALUES (#{ MY_VALUES }) RETURN @rid;"
```

What is going on?

[As per the official reference](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/SQL-Insert.html), this should have worked.

Comment: @wolf4ood The whole query result

Comment: If you execute the insert from console/studio?